# How to create a TypeGuard that mimics isinstance

Tags: python, typeguards

I have to check an object that may have been created by an API.
When I try using `isinstance(obj, MyClass)` it get a `TypeError` if `obj` was created by the API.

I wrote a custom function to handle this.

```py
def is_instance(obj: Any, class_or_tuple: Any) -> bool:
    try:
        return isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

The issue I am having is using `is_instance()` instead of the builtin `isinstance()` does not have any TypeGuard support, so the type checker complains.

```py
def my_process(api_obj: int | str) -> None:
    if is_instance(api_obj, int):
        process_int(api_obj)
    else:
        process_str(api_obj)
```

"Type int | str cannot be assigned to parameter ..."

How could I create a TypeGuard for this function?

Comment: why are you catching `except TypeError:`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What else are they supposed to do with it? Let it crash the program?

Comment: It is used in my project [is_instance](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python_ooo_dev_tools/blob/8ac049eab014ac24145b0be33fbc385ad7afbdaa/ooodev/utils/info.py#L2163).
[Here](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python_ooo_dev_tools/blob/8ac049eab014ac24145b0be33fbc385ad7afbdaa/ooodev/calc/calc_table_col.py#L37) you can see how it may be consumed. At this point the type checkers complain. Note the # type: ignore comments.

I want to know how to create a [TypeGuard](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/) would be created for such a scenario that would please the type checkers.

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, I think so, I would want the program to crash if `isinstance` raised a `TypeError`, which means I passed something totally unexpected to the second argument.

Comment: it's straightforward if you are fine restricting the second argument to only a single `type` object

Comment: No, can't be limited as the [is_instance()](https://github.com/Amourspirit/python_ooo_dev_tools/blob/8ac049eab014ac24145b0be33fbc385ad7afbdaa/ooodev/utils/info.py#L2163) is for general use in a framwork. must be able to pass any type like the built in `isinstance()` can process.

Comment: @AmourSpirit according to the docstring, it only needs to handle the case of a tuple of types, no? I'm not sure if the full one is feasible, because it is defined recursively.

Comment: If you're really dealing with an object where simply calling `isinstance(api_obj, int)` raises a `TypeError`, that's a serious upstream issue that you should report to whoever maintains the code for that object.

Comment: It's very hard for such a thing to even happen, though. The object would have to raise a `TypeError` when `isinstance` tries to access its `__class__` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate `is_instance` with a [`TypeGuard`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/) that narrows the type to that of the second argument. To handle a tuple of types or such tuples as `class_or_tuple`, use a type alias that allows either a type or a tuple of the type alias itself:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
ClassInfo: TypeAlias = type[T] | tuple['ClassInfo', ...]

def is_instance(obj: Any, class_or_tuple: ClassInfo) -> TypeGuard[T]:
    try:
        return isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

But then, as @user2357112 points out in the comment, `TypeGuard` isn't just meant for narrowing by type, but also value, so failing a check of `is_instance(api_obj, int)` doesn't mean to the type checker that `api_obj` is necessarily `str`, so using an `else` clause would not work:

```
def my_process(api_obj: int | str) -> None:
    if is_instance(api_obj, int):
        process_int(api_obj)
    else:
        # mypy complains: Argument 1 to "process_str" has incompatible type "int | str"; expected "str"  [arg-type]
        process_str(api_obj)
```

so in this case you would have to work around it with a redundant call of `is_instance(api_obj, str)`:

```
def my_process(api_obj: int | str) -> None:
    if is_instance(api_obj, int):
        process_int(api_obj)
    elif is_instance(api_obj, str):
        process_str(api_obj)
```

Demo with mypy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=4cea456751dff62c3e0bc998b74462f5

Demo of type narrowing with a tuple of types with mypy: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=98ca0795a315e541c4b1b9376d81812f

EDIT: For PyRight as you requested in the comment, you would have to make the type alias generic:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
ClassInfo: TypeAlias = Union[Type[T] , Tuple['ClassInfo[T]', ...]]

def is_instance(obj: Any, class_or_tuple: ClassInfo[T]) -> TypeGuard[T]:
    try:
        return isinstance(obj, class_or_tuple)
    except TypeError:
        return False
```

This would make mypy complain, however, so it's really down to different type checkers having different interpretations to the Python typing rules.

Demo with PyRight [here](https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBALgngBwJYDsDmB9ApgDxllAZyTCKiQgTBBigBVEsA1AQxABp7GBxAVzYAmnBgiwBBADZIWhTmJRxhjYbwQSsAWABQoSLESo05StVoBVFCRScQWAG5YWEjPFHbtdKAF4uo1iAAKAHI6IIBKbQBhCRlCAEkUYDAALl9xKRlvKAsrAG0RLHyAXSgVNUKg6NiEpOKgzgA6JqKi9y0BLGByQgxUQhgWFABjLACwACMAK1T5RSghmMIe6hdVdVSqpZqwYrCoAFoAPjS%2BQWLk7Sgr2BA4C61rx6hbGF4QFG6%2BgeHRicnOBaxDArV7lCIPa64EYIWgFACiIHAIHuT2uLzeHwAYk5CJotNoOl0EOARkteigYBh%2BoEkKkcqRcqgYJxqUUwijrghYm1CVBiWBST0pP0ArSoMKYOzLpzufj2p0oBA4Bh%2BYKAixkMCpnTLAymSyYCBSuKkP02QdjgA5UhYDlXJBdU3k-qDEbqzV-TiiikGkBhKUQ1GqrBkplUw3upBaybg1FXWwOJwuRiR6OxyFSR09L6u0YaqOek39ANxvkkkNC00wVN-MJAA)

Comment: the OP seems to want to be able to handle all cases of the `classinfo` argument to isinstance. Not sure how feasible that is though

Comment: Good point. I've updated the answer to handle tuples then.

Comment: The non-narrowing in the `else` clause isn't a bug. TypeGuards aren't required to return `True` for all instances of whatever type they're narrowing to. You can have a `def int_greater_than_5(arg) -> TypeGuard[int]` function that only returns True for ints greater than 5.

Comment: Ah indeed. It's how `TypeGuard` can work with `TypedDict`. Updated accordingly then.

Comment: I am attempting to use this with typing_extensions.

`Union[Type[T],` is giving me error: The variable "T" has no meaning in this context

```python
from typing import Type, TypeVar, Union

T = TypeVar("T")

try:
    from typing import TypeAlias  # type: ignore[misc]
except ImportError:
    from typing_extensions import TypeAlias
try:
    from typing import TypeGuard  # type: ignore[misc]
except ImportError:
    from typing_extensions import TypeGuard
ClassInfo: TypeAlias = Union[Type[T], Tuple["ClassInfo", ...]]
```

and ...

Comment: ClassInfo error: Variable not allowed in Type expression.


`@classmethod
def is_instance(cls, obj: Any, class_or_tuple: ClassInfo) -> TypeGuard[T]:
    pass
`

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting...

Although it works on [mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=1ebc96efa3580767db795493b6b5c1e7) not working for PyRight

Comment: Something seems not right with the solution above.
`reveal_type()` is reporting never.

See [link](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=bcfd1f864b834d2c5096a8f6aa162141)

Comment: @AmourSpirit I've updated the answer with a solution for PyRight. The solution would make mypy complain, however, so it's really down to different type checkers having different interpretations to the Python typing rules. `reveal_type` reporting `Never` from mypy is really a bug it seems, whereas PyRight reports the type properly.

Comment: @blhsing Amazing. I can live with this solution.
One issue is it does now work when using 'else:' instead of 'elif is_instance(api_obj, list):`
See _tinyurl.com/ymrwwqlh (remove leading _)

Comment: @AmourSpirit Unfortunately that behavior is by design, as already pointed out. Quote from [PEP-647](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/), "User-defined type guards apply narrowing only in the positive case (the if clause). The type is not narrowed in the negative case." Also refer to [Enforcing Strict Narrowing](https://peps.python.org/pep-0647/#enforcing-strict-narrowing) in the rejected ideas, where making strict narrowing even optional was deemed "cumbersome and unnecessary".